# Cannot set selected attribute for dynamically loaded Ionic2 ion-select

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to load `<ion-select>` dynamically.It is working fine.Now I need to set default selection.I have used `selected` attribute for that.But it is not working.Can you tell me why?

Here is the [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sWno6H?p=preview)

*app/home.page.html*

```
 <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Donation</ion-label>
      <ion-select>
        <ion-option *ngFor="let date of donationDates" value="{{date.donationdate}}" selected="date.isChecked">
          {{date.donationdate}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

*app/home.page.ts*

```
export class HomePage {
  donationDates:any=[];

  constructor(public navController: NavController) { 
      this.donationDates = [
       {
          id: null,
          donationid: "2",
          donationdate: "2017-03-12",
          datedescription: "Vad Bij",
          isChecked:true
      },
      {
        id: null,
       donationid: "2",
       donationdate: "2017-03-19",
       datedescription: "Sud satam",
       isChecked:false
     }]
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
[selected]="date.isChecked"
```

Your Forked [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uFrBe2?p=preview)

Comment: Oh..It seems doc is wrong or what is your thoughts?https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/